PayTM allinoneSdk React Native promise not resolved not rejected iOS
The promise from AllInOneSDKManager.startTransaction() does not get resolved, and does not get rejected.
Behaves like there is no promise.
react native: 74.5
paytm_allinonesdk_react-native: 1.2.2
Xcode: 15.0
Sometimes promise gets resolved and PayTM starts. But the most of the times PayTM does not launch.
AllInOneSDKManager.startTransaction(
        data.ORDER_ID,
        data.MID,
        txnToken,
        data.TXN_AMOUNT,
        data.CALLBACK_URL,
        false,
        true,
        "paytm"+data.MID
    )
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('paytmPayment result:', result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });


PayTM team released an update of paytm_allinone_react-native as version 1.2.3 and this solved the problem. Thank you PayTM team!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/paytm_allinone_react-native?activeTab=versions
